# Plot PyqtGraph String and Float

Tags: python, plot, graph, graphics, pyqtgraph

I can't plot with non-float X axis, I mean i want it to show data value, as '1-2020', it's working showing 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 but when is a new year it shouldnt be either as 13,14,15... etc (besides they are working as float, if i zoom the month 1,2,3,4,5... goes to decimals) and we know that months can't be float but when i try to convert all theses months to show as "1-2020" "2-2020" it gives me an error, trying with graphicsView.plot option: "Value error: Could not convert string to float: '1-2020'

Code:

```
                x = ['1-2020']
                y = [2.514]
                pen = pg.mkPen(color=(255, 0, 0))
                tela_graficos.graphicsView.plot(
                    x, y, name="IGVj", pen=pen, symbol='+')
```

Shown error:

```
line 2582, in mostrar_graficos
        tela_graficos.graphicsView.plot(
      File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\PlotItem\PlotItem.py",
line 660, in plot  
        item = PlotDataItem(*args, **kargs)
      File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\PlotDataItem.py",
line 223, in __init__   
        self.setData(*args, **kargs)
      File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\PlotDataItem.py",
line 595, in setData    
        self.updateItems( styleUpdate = self.property('styleWasChanged') )
      File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\PlotDataItem.py",
line 653, in updateItems
        self.scatter.setData(x=x, y=y, **scatterArgs)
      File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\ScatterPlotItem.py",
line 506, in setData 
        self.addPoints(*args, **kargs)
      File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\ScatterPlotItem.py",
line 590, in addPoints
        newData['x'] = kargs['x']
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1-2020'
```

Images:

1. Could not convert string to float [image: Value Error: Could not convert string to float: '1-2020']

Reproducing it working with "month" as float

2. same months working but zoomed in, the months shouldnt be showing decimals, so I would like to convert to string format on AXIS X  [image: same months working but zoomed in, the months shouldnt be showing decimals]
3. it works with months as numbers since 1,2..13,14,15,16, etc, but i would like to AXIS X show as STRING or DATETIME since from month 1 = "1-2020", example month 13 should be "1-2021"
   [image: it works with months 13,14,15,16, etc]

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc done